# Populate countries from json file to angular2-multiselect

Tags: javascript, angular, multi-select

I wanted tried load countries from a json file url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sagarshirbhate/Country-State-City-Database/master/Contries.json to angular2-multiselect. Here below is my code

```
getCountries(){
this.country.allCountries().
subscribe(
    data2 => {
      this.countryInfo = data2.Countries.CountryName;
      console.log('Data:', this.countryInfo);
    },
    err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('complete')
 )
}
```

so getcountry function getting data from a service i have created with the url here is the service

```
  export class CountriesService {
  url: string = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sagarshirbhate/Country-State-City- 
  Database/master/Contries.json";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 allCountries(): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.get(this.url);
 }
 }
```

this show Data: undifined at console log. Please help me for solve it

Comment: First try "this.countryInfo = data2.Countries;" & check if you get an array.

Comment: Could you please `console.log` your `data2`? We can get actual response of service.

Comment: @MohanRajput I am getting data at console correct, but this giving me full list of json data, but I need only countryName from the json

Comment: So i guess you need to loop the data2.Countries array, then you will get the countryList. data2.Countries[0].CountryName, data2.Countries[1].CountryName.... data2.Countries[n].CountryName

Comment: @MohanRajput yes right, I wanted to get all countries at my angular2-multiselect dropdown also based on country selection state will show up at another dropdown. Forexample if select country India then at other dropdown the states for india will load

Comment: create stacblitz of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the below code to get **CountryName**.

```
getCountries(){
 this.countryInfo = [];
this.country.allCountries().
subscribe(
    data2 => {
     
        data2.Countries.forEach(element => {
          this.countryInfo.push(element.CountryName);
        });
      console.log('Data:', this.countryInfo);
    },
    err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('complete')
 )
}
```

Comment: can you please help me for another issue like i wanted to loaded states at another multiselect based on country selection?

Comment: here is the stackbitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-jvxcbx

Comment: post another question for this.

Comment: I have posted another one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63127811/populate-state-and-cities-based-on-country-and-states-selection-at-angular2-mult

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218729/discussion-between-surendra-kumar-and-mdkamrul).