# Populate state and cities based on country and states selection at angular2-multiselect

Tags: javascript, angular

I wanted to load state and city based on country selection. I am loading json data from json file with service
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sagarshirbhate/Country-State-City-Database/master/Contries.json.
I have created full code at stacblitz here is url https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-jvxcbx
please help me for this

Comment: please check your stackblitz code, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

load state based on the country as below.

write this in getCountries();

```
this.allCountries = data2.Countries;
```

declare the below variable.

```
allCountries:any = [];
```

write code on selection of country.

```
onItemSelect1(item: any) {
    console.log(item);
    console.log(this.selectedItems1);
    this.dropdownList2 = this.allCountries.map(x=>item.itemName == x.CountryName);
    console.log(this.dropdownList2);//implement in your state dropdown
  }
```